# How to convert Subsonic MVC 1.0 to MVC 2.0 final?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, subsonic3

Here is the subsonic asp.net mvc application
http://subsonicproject.com/docs/MVC_Starter_Template

but its for MVC 1.0. How can i convert it to MVC 2.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently had to do this. The easiest way I found was to create a new MVC 2 project in a different directory. Then I did a diff on the two project files, using BeyondCompare. This told me where the differences were in terms of Library references, directories and files. There were also a few values to set within the project file such as ProjectType. Then I did the same comparison on the config files. It didn't take long and it increased my understanding of what makes up a MVC 2 project.

Answer (score 1):

I used this little tool recently and it worked perfectly:

http://weblogs.asp.net/leftslipper/archive/2009/10/19/migrating-asp-net-mvc-1-0-applications-to-asp-net-mvc-2.aspx